# Помогите с angular + framework7

Tags: angularjs, framework7

Делаю приложение мобильное на html. fw7+angular
а точнее делаю свайп список - удаление элементов.

список из 3х элементов
проблема в том, что при свайпе удаляется элемент и потом angular должен вывести 2 элемента, но выводиться потом 1
с точки зренияjs все работает как надо массив уменьшится верно
проблема либо с выводом либо с framework7, который обрабатывает нажатия на del.

если удаляем снизу по одному все вроде работает хорошо,
но если начинаем сверху, то сразу по два почему то.

вообще не понимаю как? или может подскажите ссылку на рабочий пример. мне нужно именно чтобы был массив js, т.к. массив я храню в localstore и обновляю при удалении содержимое. (само сохранение я не включил пример)

**[Пример на Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8GPWoeEtjqQSMNcVMJCS?p=preview)**

```js
// Init angular
var MyApp = {};
MyApp.config = {};
MyApp.angular = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.fw7 = {
  app: new Framework7({
    animateNavBackIcon: true
  }),
  options: {
    dynamicNavbar: true,
    domCache: true
  },
  views: []
};

// массив с элементами
var histories = [{
    sum: 11111,
    iz: 2,
    v: 3,
    itog: Math.random()
  },
  {
    sum: 22222,
    iz: 2,
    v: 3,
    itog: Math.random()
  },
  {
    sum: 33333,
    iz: 2,
    v: 3,
    itog: Math.random()
  }
];

var histories2 = [{
    sum: 6655,
    iz: 2,
    v: 3,
    itog: Math.random()
  },
  {
    sum: 4455,
    iz: 2,
    v: 3,
    itog: Math.random()
  },
  {
    sum: 5566,
    iz: 2,
    v: 3,
    itog: Math.random()
  }
];

MyApp.angular.controller('DetailPageController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    'use strict';

    // запускается 1 раз при старте
    $scope.histories = histories;
    $scope.count = 1;

    $scope.onDelete = function(i) {
      console.log('del ' + i);
      // удаляем элемент по индексу
      histories.splice(i, 1);
      // это просто счетчик в коде. он корректно работает! все норм с ним
      $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
      // а вот тут проблемы. сюда я передаю измененный массив. и выходит 1... кароч хз толи ангулар врет толи fw7
      $scope.histories = histories;
      //$scope.$apply();
      return true;
    };

    $scope.onAdd = function(i) {

      // это просто счетчик в коде. он корректно работает! все норм с ним
      $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
      // а вот тут проблемы. сюда я передаю измененный массив. и выходит 1... кароч хз толи ангулар врет толи fw7
      $scope.histories = histories2;
      //$scope.$apply();
      return true;
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/1.3.1/css/framework7.ios.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/1.3.1/css/framework7.ios.colors.min.css">

<div ng-app="MyApp" data-page="detailsPage" class="page" ng-controller="DetailPageController">
  <div class="page-content">
    count = {{count}}
    <div class="list-block">
      <div class="list-group">
        <ul>
          <!-- шаблон вывода для angular -->
          <li ng-repeat="h in histories track by $index" class="swipeout">
            <div class="item-content swipeout-content" style="">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">{{h.sum}} {{h.iz}} = {{h.itog|number:4}} {{h.v}}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swipeout-actions-right">
              <!-- ng-click="onDelete($index)"
              data-confirm="Are you sure want to delete this item?" data-id="{{$index}}"  -->
              <a ng-click="onDelete($index)" href="#delete" class="swipeout-delete">Delete</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a ng-click="onAdd()" href="#add" class="button">history</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/1.3.1/js/framework7.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: все таки думаю проблема с fw7 я сделал там кнопку история. она выводит снова 3 элемента. вот если перед этим удалить первый. то после кнопки выведет только 2 (3й скрыт почему то)

Comment: [mcve] должен быть непосредственно в вопросе

Comment: да я хотел выложить куда то типа jsfiddle.net, но там у меня не работает... может еще подскажите такие сервисы - выложу туда

Comment: Например: [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue), [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/)

Comment: оо крутой сервис - выложил http://plnkr.co/edit/8GPWoeEtjqQSMNcVMJCS?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите из вывода `ng-repeat="h in histories"` `track by $index`, он тут не нужен и ломает логику.

Comment: допиши пояснение почему `track by $index` может ломать логику

Comment: если я уберу, будут ошибки при дублировании. с выводом проблем нет. все выводит хорошо. проблема при действии del

Comment: Делайте трек по чему нибудь другому, например по id. track by $index работает не так как вы думаете. Удалив 0 элемент, он больше не будет показан (а в массиве поле удаления 0 элемента 1 элемент стал 0 и он больше не отображается). Посмотрите пример http://plnkr.co/edit/LUar5ni0RrelQGPNRkiC?p=preview и удаляйте там всегда верхний элемент. Кажется что в консоли всегда будет `del 0` но это не так! А вот тут все ок http://plnkr.co/edit/CvncsH4RnLoWUbO50sHs?p=preview

Comment: о как... спасибо. буду копать смотреть как будет работать все без track
ну я помню я этот трек поставь потому что у меня была ошибка дублирования. вычитал, что можно трек индекс поставить...